# Will using value receiver for a method on a struct that contains a http.Client affect connection pooling?

Tags: http, go, pointers, connection-pooling

My understanding of the uses of pointer receiver and value receiver is rather weak. Here's a scenario where I can't decide between the two:

I recently learned to re-use `http.Client` objects already created instead of creating a new `http.Client` each time, in order to benefit from connection pooling. So I did something like this:

```golang
type MailClient struct {
    HTTPClient *http.Client

    // ... bunch of other stuff
}

func newMailClient( // ... arguments for initializing stuff ) *MailClient {
    return &MailClient{
        HTTPClient: &http.Client{},

        // ... init other stuff
    }
}

func (c *MailClient) SendMail( // ... arguments that form a email request ) {
    // ... prepare the email request

    httpResp, err := c.HTTPClient.Do( // ... args for sending )
    if err != nil {
        // ... handle error
    }
    defer httpResp.Body.Close()

    // ...
}
```

This way, as long as `SendMail()` is called on the same `MailClient`, I expect the connection pool to kick in (I understand the default `MaxIdleConnsPerHost` of the `http.Transport` is default to `2` without customization).

But notice I defined `SendMail()` to use a pointer receiver? Yup, I don't really know why I did it. I'm just hoping by using a pointer receiver, each time the method is called, it's the same instance of `MailClient` that's doing the work, and not a copy of it. I also thought the fact that value receiver prevents modifying the receiver is because it's a copy.

I also cautiously defined the `HTTPClient` field in the `MailClient` struct to be a pointer of `http.Client`, for the same reason - I don't know how value pointer works.

So here's to summarise my question:

1. Will value receivers result in a copy of the receiver being used in the method?
2. Will changing the receiver type to `MailClient` affect the connection pooling behavior?
3. Will changing the `HTTPClient` field to a `http.Client` affect the connection pooling behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most important part to remember is that method calls translate to function calls with receivers. All rules that apply to function calls apply to method calls with the correspondent type of receiver (value or reference). A good way to see this is by using the following syntax

```
type XType struct {
    A int
    B *int
}

func (x XType) Mutate() {
    x.A = 1
    *x.B = 2
}

func (x *XType) MutateRef() {
    x.A = 2
    *x.B = 3
}

func main() {
    i := 5
    x1 := XType{
        A: 9999,
        B: &i,
    }
    //calling Mutate as a function passing the receiver by value
    XType.Mutate(x1)
    log.Printf("%#v", x1)
    log.Printf("%#v", *x1.B)
    //calling MutateRef as a function passing the receiver by reference
    (*XType).MutateRef(&x1)
    log.Printf("%#v", x1)
    log.Printf("%#v", *x1.B)
}
```

Another thing to note is that when structs are passed by value, all fields are copied, imagine a pointer as an int, so a copy will still hold the same address value.

Now, it's easy to follow the answers for your questions:

1. Will value receivers result in a copy of the receiver being used in the method?

   Yes, because is the same thing as calling a function passing a value, same rules apply
2. Will changing the receiver type to MailClient affect the connection pooling behavior

   Not really, since the client is a pointer. Even if you call the method using a value receiver, you will still be using the client pointed by the value in your copy
3. Will changing the HTTPClient field to a http.Client affect the connection pooling behavior?

   I don't think so, as the http.Transport is in charge of connection pooling and it is set by reference to the http.Client. Still, your best bet is to go with a pointer to a client

Answer (score 3):

Connection pooling is implemented in [http.Transport](https://godocs.io/net/http#Transport). Your application uses the [default transport](https://godocs.io/net/http#DefaultTransport) because the application does not set the [client transport field](https://godocs.io/net/http#Client.Transport).

No matter what the application does with pointer vs value receivers, there is no impact on connection pooling because the application uses the [default transport](https://godocs.io/net/http#DefaultTransport).

Comment: Hi sorry for not making it clear. So why connection pooling didn't work earlier was because I used to create a new `http.Client` every time in my `SendMail()`. The confusion was really mostly about value vs pointer receiver.

Comment: Good to know. But if a custom `Transport` is used to initialize one of the http.Client instead, then this client will not be pooling with other client instances. Is my understanding correct?